# HttpRequest url for a REST service with proxy

Tags: url, proxy, httprequest

How http request will work if the request endpoint URL with proxy?

e.g. URL is https://?https://

Parameters: Parameter1

But when I pass the parameters to the actual_service in my tool which is java based, the request is send in the below format instead of the proper one.

?parameter1=value1

Expected: ??parameter1=value1

Any thoughts on why it is terminating the URL string after first "?" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify
Parameter Rest URL's have the following format

```
   http://www.example.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

the '?' is at the end of url and start of parameters.

the '&' is the delimiter used between your parameters

Comment: But in my case the URL will have '?' (a delimiter) between proxy and actual endpoint.  e.g. <proxy_url>?<endpoint>?param1=value1&param2=value2.  Is this a possible request?

Comment: the '?' is a reserved character in HTTP request URLs.
You must use it only as start of your parameters and not before.